# SQL Window Function and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I have the JPARepository with the query below where I am trying to extract a running total of the fees recorded in the database.  It only works if I run the SQL query directly in the database but if I use it in the spring program it throws exceptions:

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT id                      as id,\n" +
            "       currency_code           as currency,\n" +
            "       entry_type              as entryType,\n" +
            "       original_transaction_id as originalTransactionId,\n" +
            "       tax                     as tax,\n" +
            "       transaction_amount      as amount,\n" +
            "       transaction_type        as transactionType,\n" +
            "       transaction_date        as transactionDate,\n" +
            "       runningBalance\n" +
            "FROM (select imt_tax_suspense_account.id,\n" +
            "             imt_tax_suspense_account.currency_code,\n" +
            "             imt_tax_suspense_account.entry_type,\n" +
            "             imt_tax_suspense_account.original_transaction_id,\n" +
            "             imt_tax_suspense_account.tax,\n" +
            "             imt_tax_suspense_account.transaction_amount,\n" +
            "             imt_tax_suspense_account.transaction_type,\n" +
            "             imt_tax_suspense_account.transaction_date,\n" +
            "             SUM(imt_tax_suspense_account.tax)\n" +
            "                 OVER ( order by imt_tax_suspense_account.transaction_date) AS runningBalance\n" +
            "      from imt_tax_suspense_account\n" +
            "      where imt_tax_suspense_account.transaction_date between ?1 and ?2) as nestedQuery", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<TaxStatement> getAllTaxTransactionsRunningBalance(Instant startDate, Instant endDate, PageRequest of);
```

with interface TaxStatement below:

````
public interface TaxStatement {

    Long getId();

    Instant getTransactionDate();

    Long getOriginalTransactionId();

    String getTransactionType();

    String getEntryType();

    BigDecimal getTransactionAmount();

    BigDecimal getTax();

    CurrencyCode getCurrencyCode();
} ```

when I run the query on Mariadb, I get results, but when i run it inside my Spring program, i get the error below: 


2021-06-24 23:52:32,461 ERROR org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [http-nio-8105-exec-5] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where) from imt_tax_suspense_account
      where imt_tax_suspense_account.tra...' at line 1
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1688)
    at 
.
.
.
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)


I am not sure what I am getting wrong.
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are connecting to a different database then. There is no reason for Hibernate or Spring Data JPA to handle such a native query differently than any of your querying tools.